# iOS Simulator: Save the image / recording to the destination immediately

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, screenshot, screen-recording

With Xcode 13 it's possible to make a screen recording of the iOS Simulator. However, after the screen recording has finished the actual `.mp4` file doesn't show up at the destination folder (Desktop) immediately and it takes about 5 seconds to save it there.

Meanwhile, the Simulator shows the video attached to the bottom right corner "inviting" the user to drag it somewhere.

Is there an option, or `defaults` setting that can override this behavior, so that the video/screenshot is going to be saved immediately, without the need for the view at the right corner to disappear or without a manual need to drag the screenshot/video to the destination folder?

**Example:**

Here's the video recording being saved, but if you actually check out the destination directory in Finder, you won't find it there. Any ways to expedite this process?

[image]